# Flux design pattern and good practices

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, flux

This is going to be lengthy post, containing my questions, backed with examples from the first **Flux** project, I recently created, using **Alt** implementation. I will split it into two sections and try to numerate my questions, for easier responses. If you know a good place where I can read about the topic - please share. I've done my reading, but I find it a bit hard to locate information regarding to general. best practices. Here we go.

### Section 1: General questions

*1) Multiple **stores** per **view component***

Is it a good practice for a single **container** (or **higher order component**) to depend on multiple **stores**. That may cause a lot of unused properties in the component's state. Is that a problem? If it is I could get state like this:

```
//constructor
this.state = { 
    field1: // from Store1
    field2: // from Store2
}

//componentDidMount
Store1.listen(this.updateFromStore1)
Store2.listen(this.updateFromStore2)

//updateFromStore1
this.setState({
    field1: state.field1
});
```

I think such an approach would separate the data across **stores** very well - **UserStore** will only hold info about the user, **{data}Store** will only hold information about it's type of data. And every component can take whatever it needs from all the stores.  Or should it be more like - every **container** has its own **store**, which would lead to data-repetition, but cleaner project.

*2) Use single **store** for multiple **components***

For example - a **FormStore**, which is responsible for holding information about every form in our application. all fields of our forms are held there, and only those of the currently mounted **component**(for example **UserRegister**) are initialized and used. This may result in a lot of unused fields, with null value in the **state**, but again we could prevent that, if we select only the fields we are using, as I described above.

*3) What should be responsible for loading the initial data?*

I designed my app in a way that when a component mounts, it fires action method, which calls server for data, and then fires a **Success** of **Fail** action, which updates the **store**. But i read somewhere that **stores** can get the initial data internally, and then **actions** will be used only to change that **data**. If stores are to be responsible for this, when and how should that work?

*4) The concept for **actions**:*

Are actions supposed to drive everything, or are they only necessary when we update data. For example I have tried redirecting within actions and I get **simultaneous actions error**, because the component I redirected to, fires action inside `componentDidMount` to get more data. Maybe this would not be a problem if a **store** handles initial data internally.

*5) Use **actions** and **stores**, to cut down on passing a lot of props:*

For example, I my user logic (login, logout) is handled by `App` **container** component. Under `App` I have `Navbar` and then `NavbarUserMenu`. This user menu has to show "Profile" and "Logout", if user is logged in, and "Login", "Register". So instead of passing down two functions and a boolean all the way down - I use `UserActions` and `UserStore` inside `NavbarUserMenu`. I know that this approach to user authentication is not very good, but that's just the simplest example.

### Section 2: Problems I faced in my recent app

*1) User authorization*

**URL** based restriction is easy. I used another **HOC** on top of my **container**,  which listened to **UserStore** and redirected to Login page, if there is no logged in user. But how would I hide a button, down in my **component chain**? I used the same approach (but instead of redirecting, I just didn't render the button). But that's sort of violation of **Flux**'s rule, that all **actions** and **stores** should be operated by the **container components** only. Is there a better approach.

*2) Self-contained **statefull** components*

**Flux** docs say that best case would be if all **view components** are **stateless**. But what If I have an **expandable view component**? For example I have a box, with Book summary and a Read more button. When the button is pressed the box expands and additional information is shown. My solution would be to keep a state self-contained inside the component, which holds component-specific information. Logically I don't think there is any point for stores, which don't hold actual data. Any thoughts?

*3) Forms located **lower** in the component chain*

This may be similar to 2), but I think forms are a bit different. For Example, I have list of movies, on every movie you can click the "Comments" button, which will show the comments and also a form, to add new comment. How to handle that form? Self-contained logic and state? What I did was to add **comment** field to my **FormStore**, and reuse it and **FormActions** (The same **actions** and **stores** I use for every from there is in my app).

Comment: I appreciate that you've put plenty of effort into your question, but you're asking too many things at once. Each question should be about a specific thing.

Comment: @TomFenech So I should split this up in 5-10 different topics? That's odd. The way I see it, everyone can come and say: "Section 2: question 3: `hisThoughts`". I really don't know where else to put this. It would look silly in **Git issue**, on flux library.

Comment: A lot of your "specific questions" aren't actually questions. These look like discussion points with no concrete answer, not a programming problem with a specific solution. I'm not sure where it fits, but that doesn't mean that it fits here!

Comment: @TomFenech Don't mean to disrespect, the fact that your're answering, means you are more active then me and know this forum better, but I've seen very well received abstract topics before. It's usually my very concrete problems, that people don't like, because from their point of view, I just didn't do enough research, while I just don't get half the stuff I read, because I am fresh. Would you suggest me to take this down?

Comment: I wouldn't rush to do anything, maybe other people think your question is fine, I'm just telling you what I think.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick answer to Section 1 1)

I dont know which flux implementation you are using, but having different stores (say userstore and datastore) is not that much different than having one store with the following root structure : { user: ..., data: ... }

As long as you can register to a specific object in your store it will behave the same.

The question rather revolves around 'are there any difference in the lifecycle of my information'.

For instance, I usually store some information (such as 'username') in the local storage. To easen that i gather all the data that should be stored locally together into a specific store that will serialize itself + reload itself initially.

I dont see the point of having 1 store per component, if the data is only internal then using the state is enough.

Comment: You are on spot. I forgot to mention, that I am using Alt. The idea, behind separating UserStore and DataStore, is to avoid over-complicating the data structure inside the store. I think that it could cause problems with larger data. For example If to retrieve something I need I have to do a lot of filtering and cycling.